There is a webcache issue with Nextjs 14 the JS does not work
This  is the error:
GET https://freed.care/_next/static/chunks/webpack-a2c189ab98bc87a8.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
This URL for cache https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/
I am using it like this.
const nextConfig = {
async headers() {
return [
{
source: '/_next/static/:path*', // This matches both API routes and static files
headers: [
{
key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
value: '*', // or specify your specific origin if needed
},
],
},
];
},
};`
Can someone help set up the next.config.js?
I am facing the issue mostly in the web cache.
